# .htaccess rewrite rule ignoring GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ajax/favourite/([^/]*)$ ajax/favourite/user/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Which works fine, but this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ajax/favourite/remove/([^/]*)$ ajax/favourite/remove/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Always returns index.php as the user in the link. I've tested that the ?user is being set and it is, even when the URL is ../remove/username it doesn't show username as the ?user information, it shows 'index.php'.

I can't understand why this is not working as the one before it is identical except by one directory and it works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change your rewrite it in:

```
RewriteRule ^/ajax/favourite/([^/]+)$ /ajax/favourite/user/index.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/ajax/favourite/remove/([^/]+)$ /ajax/favourite/remove/index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Please note **I have added a `/` in front of your regex** and changed `*` in `+` within the backreferences, because in both you should expect to have at least one characters as username.

I can also suggest, if you can't figure out why your rewrite rule isn't working as expected, you could enable the rewrite log in apache configuration. Your virtual host should be the best place where put this:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog /var/log/http/yourserver.log
```

Rewrite log will show you all the assumptions and action taken by apache during the request handling. You'll see there exactly what's wrong with your rewrite rule.

**Please note this log should be disabled in production.**

I have also replicated your case in my environment, this the log you should expect to see when a rewrite rule is correctly matched:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /ajax/favourite/remove/provola
(3) applying pattern '^/ajax/favourite/([^/]+)$' to uri '/ajax/favourite/remove/provola'
(3) applying pattern '^/ajax/favourite/remove/([^/]+)$' to uri '/ajax/favourite/remove/provola'
(2) rewrite '/ajax/favourite/remove/provola' -> '/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php?user=provola'
(3) split uri=/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php?user=provola -> uri=/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php, args=user=provola
(2) local path result: /ajax/favourite/remove/index.php
(2) prefixed with document_root to /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php
(1) go-ahead with /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php [OK]
```

**Update**

So why your configurations have so strange behavior (working or not)? Without more information (i.e. full rewritelog of your tentatives), I'm unable to give an answer.

In the beginning I haven't got that, both your configurations (first in question and second in comments), cannot not work because of they miss a `/` in front of each rewriterule.

The evidence of this hypothesis is in rewrite log, in fourth line, there is a successful match. That match is impossibile without first `/` in rewrite pattern.
From this point forward all remaining log lines describe the behavior for a successful match.

Comment: The log isn't showing any errors, the only error it threw was: [Fri Jan 25 22:29:55.262027 2013] [core:error] [pid 2300:tid 1728] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client ::1:50190] AH00127: Cannot map GET /C:/xampp/htdocs/ajax/favourite/remove/index.php?user=username HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/users/favourites/ but that was due to a mistake which was corrected.

Comment: This is not the rewrite log.

Comment: I've got this working now. I changed the rewrite rules to: RewriteRule ^ajax/favourite/([^/]+)$ ajax/favourite/adduser/index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ajax/unfavourite/([^/]+)$ ajax/favourite/removeuser/index.php?user=$1 [L] and changed the directories accordingly. It works, but I can't explain why this works and the previous configuration didn't.

Comment: I have figured out why it is working only the first rewrite and not the second. Now I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. Could you shed some light on why my original configuration failed but my second one worked?

Comment: I have further updated my answer. As far as I understand you're not using configuration I suggested, to go more in deep I need a full rewritelog of your tentatives. In any case please try what I suggested.